# "&" and "&&" behaving very differently in R

Tags: r

I have some nonintuitive behaviour in R.

According to the documentation

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate
>   for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

Being a new to R, this does not yet trigger a full mental model of what is supposed to happen, but it sounds similar to the 'and' vs 'conditional and' seen in other programming languages (also called [Short-Circuiting Logical Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

Create a data frame:

```
mhbins <- data.frame(val=seq(0,10),bin=rep(c(NA),length.out=11))

   val bin
1    0  NA
2    1  NA
3    2  NA
4    3  NA
5    4  NA
6    5  NA
7    6  NA
8    7  NA
9    8  NA
10   9  NA
11  10  NA
```

Then patch it up:

```
mhbins$bin[1 <= mhbins$val & mhbins$val <= 7] <- "some"

   val  bin
1    0 <NA>
2    1 some
3    2 some
4    3 some
5    4 some
6    5 some
7    6 some
8    7 some
9    8 <NA>
10   9 <NA>
11  10 <NA>
```

This is expected (Note that the printout form for the the `NA` value changes. Commenter [Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai) explains that: "`NA` is the "numeric" NA, and `<NA>` is the character one, as a vector (which a df column is) can only be of one type, when you enter a character value it gets coerced to character and that's why the NA representation change.")

though, another mystery).

However, using `&&`, patch operation reduces to `NA`:

```
mhbins <- data.frame(val=seq(0,10),bin=rep(c(NA),length.out=11))

   val bin
1    0  NA
2    1  NA
3    2  NA
4    3  NA
5    4  NA
6    5  NA
7    6  NA
8    7  NA
9    8  NA
10   9  NA
11  10  NA

mhbins$bin[1 <= mhbins$val && mhbins$val <= 7] <- "some"

   val  bin
1    0 <NA>
2    1 <NA>
3    2 <NA>
4    3 <NA>
5    4 <NA>
6    5 <NA>
7    6 <NA>
8    7 <NA>
9    8 <NA>
10   9 <NA>
11  10 <NA>
```

I don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: `NA` is the "numeric" NA, and `<NA>` is the character one, as a vector (which a df column is) can only be of one type, when you enter a character value it gets coerced to character and that's why the NA representation change.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks you, I will insert your comment into the question.

Comment: In the end, this question is less about & vs && which is well answered in the link-to-duplicate but about "what does R think it is doing with '<-'". I will have to reformulate this.

Comment: The source of your question is how & and && behave, the assignment is still an assignment, you just have a glitch on the subset: mainly, only the & version will return a logical vector for all values, where && will return only one TRUE or FALSE, hence whole df or nothing.

Comment: @Tensibai Well, no because `mhbins$bin[1 <= mhbins$val && mhbins$val <= 7] <- "some"` assigns a value to some locations given by the vector expression whereas `mhbins$bin[1 <= mhbins$val && mhbins$val <= 7] ` does not yield a vector of locations, just a vector values. So R does not behave like a programming language reducing expressions. The '<-' is something which behaves like a "replace SELECT by UPDATE" in an SQL statement.

Comment: Of course `mhbins$bin[1 <= mhbins$val & mhbins$val <= 7]` does not yield a vector of position but the values where the inner of `[]` are TRUE values. Try only: `1 <= mhbins$val & mhbins$val <= 7`, you'll see this is a vector of TRUE/FALSE values, which are used to subset the column like in `mhbins$bin[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)]` would select the same thing as: `mhbins$bin[c(3,4,5)]` or `mhbins$bin[3:5]` with a range.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks. Time for more "R in Action" I reckon.

Comment: If you haven't read it already, have a look at R inferno,  getting your mind around the vectorial way of computing in R is the base for everything after, once you get the idea everything gets clearer

Comment: side note, the short circuit happens for both operators,  but at different level, an understanding of vector-based operations is necessary to get over it.

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, I will say. Not really, just somewhat like SQL. And I have the feeling the "factor" injects even more problems, what a weird concept. I will sort it out eventually.

Comment: Factors are the same thing as what you do in Sql for 'categories' to save space, an integer 'id' mapping the whole name to avoid repeating the same text N time. Kinda usual isn't it ?

Comment: TBH unless you need some categories based functions needing factors as input or hitting a memory limit, avoid them for ease of coding untill you're more comfortable with the vectorial approach, which is more or less a Select based computing in SQL. Think working on a full column of a table instead of row by row as the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '&' here returns a vector, It is 'and' operator between each pair of `1 <= mhbins$val` and `mhbins$val <= 7`
While '&&' looks at only first pair of `1 <= mhbins$val` and `mhbins$val <= 7`

Example

```
c(TRUE,TRUE) & c(FALSE,TRUE) `returns <[1] FALSE  TRUE>`
c(TRUE,TRUE) && c(FALSE,TRUE) `returns <[1] FALSE>`
```

Comment: Ok, hold on. leaving out `&` vs `&&`. So `mhbins$bin[ 1 <= mhbins$val & mhbins$val <=  7]` returns a vector. But then the assignment operation `<- "some` assigns `"some"`, not to the vector but to the row elements of `mhbins`. So either that vector contains location information about its provenance (rows of `mhbins`) or the operators determine how subexpressions are evaluated and what they return (some kind of inverse polymorphism).